# Mongodb - Search by id and embedded array value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im trying to write a function that will search for an object by ID and whether or not a value is contained in an embedded array within the object.

```
    {
"_id" : ObjectId("569bea91c0e1fee4063527ac"),
"user" : ObjectId("568c65174fee132c36e199dd"),
"votes" : 9,
"image" : "./modules/deals/client/img/uploads/1546f914dba7e1732ea853cd70d79148.jpg",
"price" : "12.95",
"retailer" : "argos.co.uk",
"voters" : [{

    "user" : ObjectId("568c65174fee132c36e199dd"),
     },
     {
     "user" : ObjectId("568c65174fee132c36e199dd"),
     },
     {
     "user" : ObjectId("568c65174fee132c36e199dd"),

}]
```

**I would like to search by the _id and the voters.user.**

I believe i need to finish this function correctly

```
exports.dealByIdAndVoter = function(req, res) {
    Deal.count({

            $where: function () {


            }

    },
        function(err, dealByIdAndVoter) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                console.log(dealByIdAndVoter);
                var data = {};
                data.count = dealByIdAndVoter;
                res.json(data);
            }
        });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need to use the `$where` function, you can construct the query with the [$or](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator in this manner:

```
Deal
  .find({
    $or: [
      // Match by _id
      { _id: req.id },
      // Match by any user in the 'voters' array with a matching 'user' field.
      { 'voters.$.user': req.id }
    ]
  })
  .count(function(err, count) {
    // Handle error here

    res.json(count);
  });
```